# Issue with IsNumeric in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server

Below is some test SQL. IsNumeric is saying the substring of `05031,` is numeric, but fails when it tries to convert it to an actual number because of the `,`.  Is this a bug in SQL?

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(20)

SET @Str = 'XYZ 505031, some text'

SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7))  ELSE 0 END, SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7)
```

Comment: Not a bug. That function is the worst named function ever. It evaluates to true when the value is able to be converted to any of a number of datatypes that sort of remotely resembles a number. Here is one of the better articles on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Comment: in this case, it's not really a problem with `ISNUMERIC` though, but with the fact that with your regional setting, you can't convert a number with a comma to `INT`, but if you try to convert it to a numeric datatype that supports comma (for instance, `MONEY`, yikes), there would be no issue

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, it is a dumb function.  I changed it to TRY_PARSE and working much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use try_cast instead, because ISNUMERIC evaluates to 1 for `5031,`

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL).
>       DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(20)

```
SET @Str = 'XYZ 505031, some text'

SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7) AS DECIMAL(10,2))  IS NOT NULL 
      THEN CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7))  
      ELSE 0 
   END, 
   SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If 2012+, you can use Try_Convert().  We use MONEY becase the this will convert the leading zero, and then we convert to int

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(20)

SET @Str = 'XYZ 505031, some text'

SELECT AsInt = IsNull(try_convert(int,try_convert(money,SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7))),0)
     , AsStr = SUBSTRING(@Str,6,7)
```

**Returns**

```
AsInt   AsStr
5031    05031,
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `substring` is also pulling a comma in the end.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, 6, 7);
```

is resulting:

```
05031,
```

Whereas,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, 6, 5);
```

is resulting:

```
05031
```

And

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@Str,6,5)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(@Str,6,5))  ELSE 0 END, SUBSTRING(@Str,6,5)
```

is resulting:

```
5031 | 05031
```

Comment: the substring is correct, ISNUMERIC was giving me an inconsistent result